# MSBuild: How to not delete EXE files post-clean?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, msbuild, msbuild-task

I'm working on a Visual C++ project where I want to distribute the binaries for the app as a tarball/zip. Unfortunately, when I build my app and go to the output directory, I see all this crud next to the executable- an IOBJ file, an IPDB file, and a PDB. I'd like for these files to be automatically cleaned out post-build so I don't have to remove them manually, but how do I configure this in MSBuild? I tried

```
msbuild Foo.sln /t:Clean
```

but that cleaned out *everything* in the output directory, including the executable itself. Rebuilding and cleaning gives the same result.

Is it possible to do this in MSBuild?

Comment: You could add a post-build step that copies what you want to distribute another directory.

Comment: The purpose of Build is to prepare for local debugging/running. The purpose of Clean is to make sure that Build is complete. Preparing a distribution is up to you. (Some make it a practice to archive PDBs for each release so they have a deeper understanding of bug reports.)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to dictate what cleaning a project will do. [Microsoft says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms171480.aspx):

> When you clean a build, all intermediate and output files are deleted, leaving only the project and component files.

You won't be able to clean the project *and* keep your exectuable; however, as @Anon Mail more-or-less suggests: you can provide a post-build event in your project that will clean out those files you aren't interested in:

```
echo Cleaning project directory
del $(OutDir)\*.iobj
del $(OutDir)\*.ipdb
```

Comment: *It isn't possible to dictate what cleaning a project will do* technically it is, for instance by altering the generated .tlog files, or by overriding the Clean target